# Reading Big Endian from Memory and Incrementing Memory

Tags: c, gcc, endianness

i dunno where is the problem exactly, but it seems when i pass 'Memory' by reference, it doesn't work. im trying to Read a Word From Memory in Big Endian and Increment Data by 2

here is how i do it

```
WORD ReadBigEndianWORD(char **Data)
{
    WORD Result = (unsigned char) *Data[0];
    Result <<= 8;
    Result |= (unsigned char) *Data[1];
    *Data++
    return Result;
}
```

and i call it like this

```
char *Memory = ........;
WORD MyWord = ReadBigEndianWORD(&Memory);
```

the code above doesn't work (works if Function Argment is 'char *Data' and Data passed as 'Memory');

and is this the best way to read Big Endian from Memory?

thanks;

Comment: why you need double pointer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is failing because of the operation precedence of the `*` operator and the `[]` operation.  The `[]` has higher precedence, so you need to change your code to:

```
WORD ReadBigEndianWORD(char **Data)
{
    WORD Result = (unsigned char) (*Data)[0];
    Result <<= 8;
    Result |= (unsigned char) (*Data)[1];
    (*Data) += sizeof(WORD);
    return Result;
}
```

The line with `*Data[0]` ends up working correctly because you're adding an offset of zero.  The second `*Data[1]` will either crash our give you bad data because it's reading for uninitialized memory.  `*Data[1]` is equivalent to `\*(\*(Data + sizeof(char**)))`, so it's tacking the the location where Memory is stored and moving past that.

The best way to see what's happening is to use your original `ReadBigEndianWORD` and change the calling code to:

```
char *Memory[2] = { "........", ",,,,,,,,," };
short Myshort = ReadBigEndianshort(Memory);
```

If you do that you'll see that *Data[1] is pointing to Memory[1].

And then to move your Data pointer to the next work you need to increment it by the sizeof a `WORD`, not the size of  `char**` which is what `++` will do.

But as everyone else has said you should change your method to take a `char*` and then worry about moving around in your buffer in the calling code.  That will make your function cleaner and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parentheses around `Data`, like so:

```
WORD Result = (unsigned char) (*Data)[0];
(*Data)++;
```

But if such things as pointers-to-pointers confuse you, you better write the code in a more simple way, like have one function read the data, and another increase the pointer. Actually, it's usually better to do unrelated things separately, and it's usually good to avoid `**` in code.

Also, you can use the following:

```
WORD ReadBigEndianWORD(unsigned char *Data)
{
    return (Data[0] << 8) | Data[1];
}
```